# AngularJS scope variable value change not reflecting across controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controlleras

In my angularjs, i have two controllers and use the variable which is referred in UI. From UI I am calling method OpenPage of NumTwoController which updates value of variable1 and NumOneController tries to access updated value.

After I update the variable in NumTwoController, newly updated value is not reflecting in NumOneController and also in NumOne.html page.

```
myModule.controller('NumOneController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 
    function ($rootScope, $scope) {
        $scope.variable1 = 1; // initial value assigned
        
        $scope.$on('NumOne', function (e, opt) {
            var valueselected = $scope.variable1; //still 1 is assigned.trying to read the value assigned in NumTwoController
        });
    }
    ]);


myModule.controller('NumTwoController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 
    function ($rootScope, $scope) {
        $scope.variable1 = [];
        
        $scope.OpenPage = function (menuItem, PageReload){
            $scope.variable1 = 2;       
        });
    }
    ]);
```

I tried adding $scope.$apply() but didnt succeed.

Guidance to reflect the updated value in the another controller is much appreciated

Comment: user services to share data between controllers.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot directly access the variable of scope of one controller to another.
You can make use **broadcast** and **on** functions or **angular service** for sharing the scope between two controllers.

check out this =>

[Share data between AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers)

https://benohead.com/blog/2016/07/18/angularjs-sharing-data-controllers/